# Count the result of a mysql count?

Tags: mysql, count, group-by

I wonder how the following could be solved with a mysql query, but don't really know how to proceed past my first count.

In a table there is user ids and an item id they have.

```
user_id | item
--------------
12      | 1
11      | 3
34      | 1
12      | 2
34      | 2
9       | 1
12      | 3
```

If I group by user_id and count the user_id, I get a list of users and how many items they have won, like:

```
user_id | count(user_id) i.e. how many items have they won
-----------------------
9       | 1
11      | 1
12      | 3
34      | 2
```

How can I in turn count how many users have won 1, 2 or 3 items, ie. count the result of the count, grouped by the count of user_id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select from the select:

```
select times_won, count(*)
from (
    select user_id, count(*) as times_won
    from my_table
    group by 1
) x
group by 1
```

Comment: Great answer! I was kind of trying to use COUNT twice, but couldn't quite put it together :) Also I wasn't familiar with count(*) + GROUP BY foobar, which seems to do the trick nicely enough here. Ty.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I've not understand the question... Can't you just use this?

```
SELECT item, COUNT(DISTINCT user_id) 
FROM ...
GROUP BY item
```

Instead, if you simply want to count rows from the *intermediate* result you posted, you can use subqueries like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (
    SELECT user_id, COUNT(user_id) AS count
    FROM ...
    GROUP BY user_id
) AS intermediate_result
GROUP BY count
```